# extracting specific columns and paste these into another text file

Tags: text-processing

I have two text files. I need to copy columns 5-6-7 of one text file and paste these columns to another text file. For example, first column of text files as follows;

text_1

```
E    GPS41  0  5.68026000000000E+08  1.09767623810000E+04 -1.66840300460000E+04  1.77051348440000E+04
```

text_2

```
E GPS41 568026000 0.000000000000000E+00 1.097676240456553E+04 -1.668403004627044E+04 1.770513486005421E+04 2.140299562139315E+00 -5.351523203487980E-01 -1.876979500368582E+00 1.714052588162549E-05 1.390618031795355E-05 8.605165964871206E-06 3.266367837880071E-09 3.392831966908295E-09 1.626218351208862E-09
```

I need to copy column 5-6-7 of text_1 and paste these to text_2 as follow;

new_text

```
   E GPS41 568026000 0.000000000000000E+00 1.09767623810000E+04 -1.66840300460000E+04  1.77051348440000E+04 2.140299562139315E+00 -5.351523203487980E-01 -1.876979500368582E+00 1.714052588162549E-05 1.390618031795355E-05 8.605165964871206E-06 3.266367837880071E-09 3.392831966908295E-09 1.626218351208862E-09
```

Note: This question is different to in my previous question.

Comment: Read `man cut;man paste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - provided you don't care about preserving the specific amounts of whitespace in your data:

```
awk '(getline line < "text_1") > -1 {split(line,a); $5 = a[5]; $6 = a[6]; $7 = a[7]} 1' text_2 > new_text
```

Ex. given

```
$ head text_{1,2}
==> text_1 <==
foo     bar  A B C D E
bar     baz  F G H I J

==> text_2 <==
        foo   bar  a b c d e f g h i j k l m
        bar   baz  f g h i j k l m n o p q r
```

then

```
$ awk '(getline line < "text_1") > -1 {split(line,a); $5 = a[5]; $6 = a[6]; $7 = a[7]} 1' text_2
foo bar a b C D E f g h i j k l m
bar baz f g H I J k l m n o p q r
```

---

The difficulty with using `cut` and `paste` is that at least one of your files has inconsistent amounts of whitespace delimiting the fields. You *could* make it work for the input you have posted as follows:

```
paste <(cut -d ' ' -f1-4 text_2) \
  <(tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' < text_1 | cut -d ' ' -f5-7) \
  <(cut -d ' ' -f8- text_2) > new_text
```

Ex.

```
$ paste <(cut -d ' ' -f1-4 text_2) \
    <(tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' < text_1 | cut -d ' ' -f5-7) \
    <(cut -d ' ' -f8- text_2) > new_text

$ diff -ws new_text your_new_text 
Files new_text and your_new_text are identical
```